# regex this code python

Tags: python, regex, string

I have this string:

```
questioncode = YED_q2_a_10
```

I want to check if the string ends with an underscore then an int

```
i.e. "_293"
```

My attempt:

```
codesplit = questioncode.split('_')[-1]

if codesplit.isdigit():
    print "true"
else:
    print "false"
```

as you can see this is not doing what I want and I believe regex is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if questioncode.count('_') and questioncode.split('_')[-1].isdigit():
    print 'true'
else:
    print 'false'
```

is perfectly fine (and I'd say preferred), why do you want to use regular expressions? They're  *absolutely unnecessary* here.

This statements check if there's at least one underscore in the string and splits the string if yes, so you won't get `Index out of range` error.

If you want you can replace `questioncode.count('_')` with `'_' in questioncode`, as suggested by @qwe.

Comment: `'_' in questioncode` makes more sense than calling `.count()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

if re.match('.*_[0-9]+$', 'YED_q2_a_10'):
    print "true"
else
    print "false"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one using `re.search()`

```
questioncode = "YED_q2_a_10"
if(re.search("_\d+$", questioncode)):
    print "yes"
```

`\d+` means any digit having one or more occurrence. And `$` means the end of the string, an [anchor](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Simply see if you can convert `string` to `int`.

Here is the code. I assume there are one or more underscore in `questioncode`, so this only works when it is.

```
questioncode = "YED_q2_a_10"
codesplit = questioncode.split('_')[-1]

try:
    int(codesplit)
    print "true"
except ValueError:
    print "false"
```